# Peculiar behavior of array_udiff?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got the following Php script:

```
<?php
function filt($k, $l){
    if($k===$l){
        var_dump("valid: ".$k."-".$l);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
$a6=array(7, 9, 3, 33);
$a7=array(2, 9, 3, 33);
$u=array_udiff($a6, $a7, "filt");
var_dump($u);
?>
```

With the following output:

```
string 'valid: 3-3' (length=10)

array
    0 => int 7
    1 => int 9
    3 => int 33
```

As I know, the array_udiff should dump the equal values and let only the different values from the first array.
What seems to be the problem here?
I run WampServer Version 2.2 on Windows 7. Php version: 5.3.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're not returning all necessary values (e.g. -1, 0, 1). See: [array_udiff](http://php.net/manual/function.array-udiff.php)

```
$a6 = array(7, 9, 3, 33);
$a7 = array(2, 9, 3, 33);

$u = array_udiff($a6, $a7, function ($k, $l){
  return $k > $l ? 1 : ($k < $l ? -1 : 0);
});

print_r($u);
```

Comment: Even subtraction is enough: `function ($k,$l) { return $k - $l; }` :)

Comment: That's even more peculiar, shouldn't it work just by returing one and zero? I mean, it's a matter of logic, if equal return 0, else some value different from zero. Shouldn't it be able to differentiate from that perspective? If not, why?

Comment: @PLB That's what I'd usually do, but wasn't too sure here. Because of how the initial code was written in the question.

Comment: @AndrewG.H. Maybe, but is that really important? If you want to use array_udiff, use it as it want's to be used.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the documentation says:

```
The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively
less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
```

You're not doing that. To make sure that you do, simply make your `filt` function return `$l - $k`

There is a simple explanation for that: the elements might be in any order. To avoid having to compare each element to every other element, it first sorts them. That's why you need + / 0 / -

Comment: Thanks for explaining not so obvious need to return -1/0/1 in callback function.